# How to disable/hide the edit form that pops up after uploading new file into Document Set (SP 2016)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

0

I have created a Document Set Content Type named "Contract" with 2 shared columns (Start Date, End Date). I have also created a Document Library named "Contracts" which use this content Type.

I have created a new contract "Contract 1" based on the "Contract" Content Type then I have uploaded a word document within the "Contract 1" Document Set, then a Edit form popped up asking for updating the Start Date and End Date properties but these 2 properties have already inherited the values of the document set's properties and I dont want the values of these 2 properties to be updated at the file level (I want them to be always the same as the values of the Document Set 's properties)

So I am asking you if there is a way to prevent the user from changing the properties values of the uploaded document, so that they always stay the same as the ones inherited from the document set which it belongs to.

Thanks,

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, there seems to be no OOB way to prevent this. You have to educate your end users not to modify the original metadata.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Allen_MSFT for your help